# Drools - Parse XML Data from Another System and Decide Business Rules

Tags: xml-parsing, drools, business-rules, kie

I have the following requirement and I not sure how to go about it using Drools.

**Background**:

- Completely new to Drools - never heard of it until last evening.
- Using Drools is mandatory
- Deadline is tomorrow :)
- I have been into Software Development for quite some time, so programming using Java is not an issue.

[image: High level view of what needs to be done]

**What happened from last night till this morning:**

- Installed Ubuntu 17.10 on VMWare Player
- Installed the docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase/
- Opened the KIE IDE
- Went through the tutorials at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/drools/ but that was more towards using Eclipse IDE not the KIE IDE I had installed.
- https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.8.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html seems to be too much to read solely because of short timeline.

I completely understand that there is no easy way to go about using new tools and technologies.

What I would like to know is to accomplish the required as in the diagram above, how do I go about it?

The tutorialspoint tutorial showed using Eclipse with DRL and Java classes, I kind of found that easier to follow and simpler compared to the KIE IDE, which is a bit overwhelming without proper studying on its usage and documentation.

Can you please tell if what I want to achieve is possible using Drools or not?

I will provide more info and clarity if you need.
Apologies if the question is a bit vague.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible and I would totally recommend you to start with a simple POC that doesn't involve the KIE Workbench at all. At the end of the day, Drools is just another Java library. There are some Eclipse plugins that facilitates some things (and adds syntax support for DRL) but they are not mandatory to be used. 
Here are some sample examples using Drools in regular Maven projects: https://bitbucket.org/drools-6-developer-guide/drools6-dev-guide/src .

Comment: @Esteban Aliverti : Thanks for the info. I have decided to go with the Java Eclipse way until I get used to the domain. After that will venture into the adventurous KIE. I am following some tutorials online on using Eclipse with Drools. It is going on well so far.